# How can I incorporate photoshop with automator?

Tags: automator, adobe-photoshop

I'm new to Automator and want to create some actions of my own, that will work with mainly Photoshop and possibly some other 3rd party apps, but the only options that appear are for Apple apps and MS Office apps.

[image]

When I Google: *How to incorporate photoshop with automator?*

I keep seeing links to download pre-made actions from robotphotoshop.com But I don't want to avoid purchasing a bunch of actions I don't need.

Do I need to create custom Apple Scripts?